# TypeScript extra keys in nested objects

Tags: typescript

My problem can be summed up with this little snippet (here's a larger, interactive example in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20X%20%3D%20%7Bx%3A%20number%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20%7By%3A%20number%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%3A%20X%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20notValid%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Nested%20values%20checked%0D%0Alet%20xx%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20X%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20notValid%3A%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20xy%3A%20X%20%26%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20notValid%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20xxy%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20X%20%7D%20%26%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20notValid%3A%201%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20why%20no%20error%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%201%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20xxy2%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20X%20%7D%20%26%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20notValid%3A%201%20%20%20%2F%2F%20error%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20notValid%3A%201%2C%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20no%20error%20here%3F%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A)):

```
type X = {x: number};
type Y = {y: number};
type XXY = { x: X } & Y;
let xxy: XXY = {
    x: {
        x: 1,
        notValid: 1   // <--- this is not an error :(
    },
    y: 1
};
```

Given that `X` and `Y` are derived in another way (and so I can't just write the `XXY` type by hand), how can I make it so that unknown keys in the nested object are treated as invalid?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18075

Comment: Interesting scenario. Also, it's interesting that if you remove `y: 1`, instead of complaining about `y` missing, it complains about `notValid` being invalid. http://prntscr.com/n36p0v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13813) where [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) doesn't apply to nested types involving unions and intersections in the way that people expect.  Excess property checking is kind of an add-on to the type system that only applies to object literals, so when it doesn't apply, things fall back to the [structural subtyping](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) rule where type `{a: A, b: B}` is a subtype of `{a: A}`, and so a value of the former type should be assignable to a variable of the latter type.  You might want to head over to [the issue in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13813) and give it a  or explain your use case if you think it's more compelling than the ones already listed there.  Hopefully there will be a fix someday.

Until then, there are workarounds.  The type-level equivalent to excess property checks are so-called [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which don't exist in TypeScript as concrete types.  There are ways to simulate them using generic helper functions and type inference... in your case it would look something like this:

```
type Exactly<T, U extends T> = T extends object ?
  { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? Exactly<T[K], U[K]> : never }
  : T

const asXXY = <T extends XXY>(x: T & Exactly<XXY, T>): T => x;

let xxy = asXXY({
  x: {
    x: 1,
    notValid: 1  // error!
  },
  y: 1
});
```

That's the error you want, right?

How it works: The helper function `asXXY<T extends XXY>(t: T & Exactly<XXY, T>)` infers the generic type `T` to be the type of the passed-in parameter `t`.  Then it tries to evaluate the intersection `T & Exactly<XXY, T>`.  If `t` is assignable to `T & Exactly<XXY, T>`, the check succeeds and the function is callable.  Otherwise, there will be an error somewhere on `t` showing where they differ.

And `Exactly<T, U extends T>` basically walks down recursively through `U`, keeping it the same as long as it matches `T`... otherwise it sets the property to `never`.

Let's expand on this difference for the above case: The inferred type for `T` was

```
{ x: { x: number; notValid: number; }; y: number; }
```

Is that assignable to `T & Exactly<XXY, T>`?  Well, what's `Exactly<XXY, T>`?  It's turns out to be

```
{ x: { x: number; notValid: never; }; y: number; }
```

which is what happens when you drill down into type `T` and notice that `notValid` can't be found inside `XXY`.

The intersection `T & Exactly<XXY, T>` is essentially just `Exactly<XXY, T>`, so now the compiler is comparing the passed-in parameter to the type

```
{ x: { x: number; notValid: never; }; y: number; }
```

which it isn't.  The `notValid` type is a `number`, not a `never`... so the compiler complains in exactly the place you want.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone landing here in 2022, check that your `tsconfig.json` does not contain:     `"suppressExcessPropertyErrors": true` , like in my case. Excess property errors are handled much better since the original post...